# R minimize portfolio function with gradient

Tags: r, optimization

I want to minimize function

```
f <- function(u){
  return(-(1+u[1]+u[2]+u[3]+u[4]))
}
```

with gradient **grad**

And I have constraints:

1) u[1]+u[2]+u[3]+u[4] = 1

2) 0<=u[1]<=1, 0<=u[2]<=1, 0<=u[3]<=1, 0<=u[4]<=1

How to make it correctly? I can make it only for 2 constraint

```
optim(par=c(0,0,0,0), fn=f,lower=c(0, 0, 0, 0), upper=c(1, 1, 1, 1),method="L-BFGS-B")
```

But 1 constraint is not true in this case

Comment: Thank you, but its incorrect too because if i make `lower=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` result will be `0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5` (1 constraint will be wrong)

Comment: I need only way to add 1 constraint

Comment: Since the sum of the u's equals 1because of (1) the objective function, `f`, equals -2 regardless of the u values.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck sure, i know it. it was comment to idea to make f = (u1+u2+u3+u4-1) and minimize it. In my task in zero iteration capital = 1 and u's is profitability.(This comment was deleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `fmincon` from package `pracma` like below

```
pracma::fmincon(c(0,0,0,0), 
        f, 
        gr = grad, 
        Aeq = cbind(1,1,1,1), 
        beq = 1,
        lb = c(0,0,0,0), 
        ub = c(1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: It seems like true solution but i have `Argument 'Aeq' must be a matrix with length(x0) columns`. Though  `length(x0) = length(Aeq) = 4`

Comment: Got it. `Aeq = cbind(1,1,1,1)`

Comment: @ИльшатМурзурбеков Great that you fixed it. Does this address your question?